# Selecting datas from 10 (same formed) tables (create view)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Actually, I have no idea how does it looks like the question's title, is it exactly related to the issue or not, but I'm gonna try explain my problem:

I have a table named as `AdvertClick` (that stores the stats of each "Advert" by "AdvertID") and `Advert` table besides (as you guess the main table that stores my ad lists). So I need to store each advert click data (i.e. "Country","Browser","Language" etc.) in `AdvertClick` table. For example, the code is below getting top country data from `AdvertClick` table.

```sql
SELECT Count(_ac.ID) AS Click, _ac.Country
FROM `Advert` _a
LEFT JOIN `AdvertClick` _ac ON _ac.AdvertID = _a.ID
WHERE _a.UserID = $UserID
GROUP BY _ac.Country
ORDER BY Click DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But, I've replicated `AdvertClick` table as `AdvertClick0, AdvertClick1 ... AdvertClick9`, because it's (the unique stats table) was getting so heavy and slower. And now, I have 10 tables and all off them are same formed (meaning table colums). I'm just inserting every click data like this;

```php
$TableName = "AdvertClick". $AdvertID % 10;
$SQL = "INSERT INTO ${TableName} ... VALUES (...)";
```

So, now I want to do same thing above but failing.
I've tried `CREATE VIEW` in very different ways like;

`CREATE ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE VIEW _tmp_ (colums...) SELECT x,y,z` -> fail
`CREATE VIEW _tmp_ (colums...) SELECT x,y,z JOIN AdvertClick0 _ac0` -> fail
etc...

Is anyone help me about this (really annoying) issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Aggregate, denormalize, and archive the data! In a similar situation, we created hourly and daily archive tables named by day, month and year that held total values. The dump table, in your case AdvertClick, never held more then 3 days of data.

Comment: @Julien I don't think about to separate tables anymore, I'm just trying to speed up my data system as many web developers do...

Comment: increasing speed was the main point of my comment :)

Comment: what part is slower?  the single table approach should not affect insert at all. (maybe updating an index has a minimal overhead).  perhaps you are optimizing in the wrong area?

Comment: according to his statement he created 10 separate tables for AdvertClick according to the name if the user clicks on the ads 1 it will be stored on AdvertClick1 table, 2nd click would be on AdvertClick2, 3rd click would be on AdvertClick3 and so on. this is how I see his current process there is no problem on this kind of approach as you may get the same result you want but having too many tables on the database (that are not reasonable) would slow down the performance of the database on which you could still have the same approach with only 1 table and that would simplify things. ;)

Answer (score 0):

hm... I think view would be appropriate for this kind of situation you should also have a good structured table to get the proper approach on this another approach I would do is to add another column that will identify what type of data are on that row for example:

table: advert

columns: name, country, type

the type will take any value you want or you may create another table and reference it from there as a foreign key to make it more flexible in that case you'll be having only 2 tables. To make if work as a view you can do it this way:

```
CREATE VIEW 'AdvertClick1' AS SELECT name, country FROM advert WHERE type = 1;
CREATE VIEW 'AdvertClick2' AS SELECT name, country FROM advert WHERE type = 2;
CREATE VIEW 'AdvertClick3' AS SELECT name, country FROM advert WHERE type = 3;
```

and so on and so forth. :)

Comment: I keep all datas as same type and using MyISAM engine. So I can't use foreing keys. It's just like this;
`INSERT INTO AdvertClick1 VALUES($AdvertID,'$Country','$Browser', ...);`
Actually, I didn't understand what you mean "type".

Comment: I see you could still use the same approach. The above statements is just a sample to explain what I mean about my statement adding a column to identify what type of data you really need the name of the column would depend on what you need. That column would be able to group your data some kind of categorizing so that you may group them accordingly instead of creating 10 tables that would have just the same columns or attributes

Comment: ok according to your statement above you could have another approach like this: ***
INSERT INTO advertClick (advertID, country, browser, click, ...) VALUES($AdvertID,'$Country','$Browser', 1, ...), ($AdvertID,'$Country','$Browser', 1, ...);
INSERT INTO advertClick (advertID, country, browser, click, ...) VALUES($AdvertID,'$Country','$Browser', 2, ...);
INSERT INTO advertClick (advertID, country, browser, click, ...) VALUES($AdvertID,'$Country','$Browser', 3, ...); ***
I tried to use "click" this time instead of "type" but they do have the same approach only that I changed the name

Comment: the point of my answer is to enable you to store the data on only 1 table instead of creating 10 tables and storing the data on each separate table when you could have only 1 table and manage them from there in that you would able to optimize the performance of your database and on which management would not be that complicated. :)

Answer (score 0):

i will propose something else entirely.

i think you should keep only one AdvertClick table - DO NOT create many of them and therefore create these other headaches.  To get you answers will be even more difficult and even more slow.

Instead, if you are sure you have optimized your queries, you may choose to denormalize selectively to gather your common statistics.

for example:

create an ON INSERT trigger on the single AdvertClick table that increments the count value in a new AdvertClickByCountry table for the current Country.  Also, create an ON DELETE trigger that decrements that count for the country.

Then your query above would be trivial - something like:

```
SELECT click_count, country 
from AdvertClickByCountry
ORDER BY Click_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```